# Magento Index Management issues, products not displaying in category pages

Tags: magento, indexing, product

This is a Magento issue - using the Enterprise edition. Unfortunately their support technicians are all in San Francisco, and I am based in the UK, so their support to me is  restricted to a certain time window.

I have categories which are active, set to display products, and/or products and static blocks, and are sub categories of the default root category.

I also have test products, which are enabled, in stock, with quantities, visible in Catalog, Search, and are assigned to these sub categories.

The problem is, my test products (or any product!) do not show on the category page. I am using the default/default themes, and have not changed the page_layout.

I have cleared/flushed all caches, and reindexed.

However, most of my indexes appear as status 'SCHEDULED' and have never been updated - there are no checkboxes next to these, so I cannot select them to 'reindex data'.

See the screenshot.

[image: Magento - Index Management]

If anyone has any clues on how to fix this, I will be very happy.

Thanks

Comment: first time seeing this kind of thing :(

Comment: don't know much about indexing but may be any of your custom extension is in conflict state. Try turning that off

Answer (score 3):

Reindex is somewhat required to display products on front, especially if you have flat tables enabled (Admin Panel > System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend: "Use Flat Catalog Category" and "Use Flat Catalog Product").

The situation with indexes is a bit of strange. It you do it on your local workstation or you have access to shell on hosting you can manually force indexes by running this command:

`pwd$ php shell/indexer.php reindexall`

If you have enabled flat tables you can try to disable them, to check if products will be visible on front.

You need to also put right permissions on var and media folders and theirs content. 755 should be ok.

Comment: Flat Catalog Category and Use Flat Catalog Products are both set to 'No', as they have always been.

Var and Media folders are also set to 0755. I havent changed anything here.

I am working on a live staging environment, and but I am not familiar with shell scripting.

Still no luck

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Thanks guys for your answers but it was none of the above.

I had installed a Product Feature module incorrectly. I was under the assumption that when developing in app/code/local/... anything that didn't work would fall back to app/code/core/...

Sadly this was not the case. My fault, and everyone knows the phrase about making assumptions.

Magento has a very steep learning curve!

Comment: I have the same issue , Only first two Index status is shown ready and rest of them is showing "Scheduled".
Can you provide me some guideline how did u fix this .
Do see all indexes now? I am using 1.13.0 version

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thats really interesting, I had a similar issue recently where a reindex was not fully working. However I didnt get scheduled being displayed.

Can I ask what version of Enterprise are you using ?

As Ventus suggested a tried and tested method of forcing a reindex is to use the shell script, To do this you need to SSH into your server. Then use the cd command ( change directory ) to where your website is located on the file system. E.g. cd /var/www/....

From here run php shell/indexer.php reindexall

Answer (score 0):

1. Set cron to run this will take care of reindexing provided you have not changed crontab values.

From your screen it looks like you have never run a cron on this setup.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code below into a .php file in your magento install and then run it from your URL, this will clean and re-index everything. You can run it from a cron job. Any errors then you have a problem with yor database in witch case you should back it up and then re-creat it in  a new DB instance.

```
    <?php

set_time_limit(0);
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/app/Mage.php';


//get all stores

$websites = Mage::app()->getWebsites();
$thisstore = $websites[1]->getDefaultStore()->getCode();



echo "Store: ".$thisstore."<br/>";

//clean var dir

$dirs = array(
        'downloader/.cache/*',
        'var/cache/',
        'var/locks/',
        'var/log/',
        'var/report/',
        'var/minifycache/',
        'var/mincache/',
        'var/tmp/'
    );

    foreach($dirs as $v => $k) {
        exec('rm -rf '.$k);
    }
/*
//clean out sessions
$dirs = array('var/session/');

    foreach($dirs as $v => $k) {
        exec('rm -rf '.$k);

    }
*/  
//clean db log files
$xml = simplexml_load_file('./app/etc/local.xml', NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$db['host'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->host;
$db['name'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->dbname;
$db['user'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->username;
$db['pass'] = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->password;
$db['pref'] = $xml->global->resources->db->table_prefix;
global $db;

    $tables = array(
        'catalogsearch_fulltext',
        'dataflow_batch_export',
        'dataflow_batch_import',
        'log_customer',
        'log_quote',
        'log_summary',
        'log_summary_type',
        'log_url',
        'log_url_info',
        'log_visitor',
        'log_visitor_info',
        'log_visitor_online',
        'importexport_importdata',
        'core_url_rewrite',
        'report_viewed_product_index',
        'report_event',
        'core_cache',
        'core_cache_option',
        'core_cache_tag'
    );

    mysql_connect($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass']) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db['name']) or die(mysql_error());

    foreach($tables as $v => $k) {
        mysql_query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; '.'TRUNCATE `'.$db['pref'].$k.'`;'.' SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1; ') or die(mysql_error());
    }

///---------------------------------//
// now run standard magento cleanup file


## Function to set file permissions to 0644 and folder permissions to 0755

function AllDirChmod( $dir = "./", $dirModes = 0755, $fileModes = 0644 ){
   $d = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $dir );
   foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $d, 1 ) as $path ){
      if( $path->isDir() ) chmod( $path, $dirModes );
      else if( is_file( $path ) ) chmod( $path, $fileModes );
  }
}

## Function to clean out the contents of specified directory

function cleandir($dir) {

    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && is_file($dir.'/'.$file)) {
                if (unlink($dir.'/'.$file)) { }
                else { echo $dir . '/' . $file . ' (file) NOT deleted!<br />'; }
            }
            else if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) {
                cleandir($dir.'/'.$file);
                if (rmdir($dir.'/'.$file)) { }
                else { echo $dir . '/' . $file . ' (directory) NOT deleted!<br />'; }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }

}

function isDirEmpty($dir){
     return (($files = @scandir($dir)) && count($files) <= 2);
}

// rebuild everything!!!
$processes = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();
$processes->walk('setMode', array(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME));
$processes->walk('save');

$processes->walk('reindexAll');
$processes->walk('reindexEverything');

echo "----------------------- CLEANUP START -------------------------<br/>";
$start = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));
echo "<br/>*************** SETTING PERMISSIONS ***************<br/>";
echo "Setting all folder permissions to 755<br/>";
echo "Setting all file permissions to 644<br/>";
AllDirChmod( "." );
echo "Setting pear permissions to 550<br/>";


echo "<br/>****************** CLEARING CACHE ******************<br/>";

if (file_exists("var/cache")) {
    echo "Clearing var/cache<br/>";
    cleandir("var/cache");
}

if (file_exists("var/session")) {
    echo "Clearing var/session<br/>";
    cleandir("var/session");
}

if (file_exists("var/minifycache")) {
    echo "Clearing var/minifycache<br/>";
    cleandir("var/minifycache");
}

if (file_exists("downloader/pearlib/cache")) {
    echo "Clearing downloader/pearlib/cache<br/>";
    cleandir("downloader/pearlib/cache");
}

if (file_exists("downloader/pearlib/download")) {
    echo "Clearing downloader/pearlib/download<br/>";
    cleandir("downloader/pearlib/download");
}

if (file_exists("downloader/pearlib/pear.ini")) {
    echo "Removing downloader/pearlib/pear.ini<br/>";
    unlink ("downloader/pearlib/pear.ini");
}

if (file_exists("media/catalog/product/cache/")) {
    echo "Removing media/catalog/product/cache/<br/>";
    unlink ("media/catalog/product/cache/");
}

if (file_exists("media/tmp/")) {
    echo "Removing media/tmp/<br/>";
    unlink ("media/tmp/");
}
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
echo "Start Cleaning all caches at ... " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "<br/>";
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
Mage::getConfig()->init();

$types = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->getTypes();

try {
    echo "Cleaning data cache... <br/>";
    flush();
    foreach ($types as $type => $data) {
        echo "Removing $type ... ";
        echo Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->clean($data["tags"]) ? "[OK]" : "[ERROR]";
        echo "<br/>";
    }
} catch (exception $e) {
    die("[ERROR:" . $e->getMessage() . "]");
}

echo "<br/>";

try {
    echo "Cleaning stored cache... ";
    flush();
    echo Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->clean() ? "[OK]" : "[ERROR]";
    echo "<br/>";
} catch (exception $e) {
    die("[ERROR:" . $e->getMessage() . "]");
}

try {
    echo "Cleaning merged JS/CSS...";
    flush();
    Mage::getModel('core/design_package')->cleanMergedJsCss();
    Mage::dispatchEvent('clean_media_cache_after');
    echo "[OK]<br/>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die("[ERROR:" . $e->getMessage() . "]");
}

try {
    echo "Cleaning image cache... ";
    flush();
    echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_image')->clearCache();
    echo "[OK]<br/>";
} catch (exception $e) {
    die("[ERROR:" . $e->getMessage() . "]");
}

echo "<br/>************** CHECKING FOR EXTENSIONS ***********<br/>";
If (!isDirEmpty("app/code/local/")) { 
    echo "-= WARNING =- Overrides or extensions exist in the app/code/local folder<br/>";
}
If (!isDirEmpty("app/code/community/")) { 
    echo "-= WARNING =- Overrides or extensions exist in the app/code/community folder<br/>";
}
$end = (float) array_sum(explode(' ',microtime()));
echo "<br/>------------------- CLEANUP COMPLETED in:". sprintf("%.4f", ($end-$start))." seconds ------------------<br/>";

//sitemap refresh
$collection = Mage::getModel('sitemap/sitemap')->getCollection();
    foreach ($collection as $sitemap) {
        try {
            $sitemap->generateXml();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

?>
```